# Is there a way to link to a specific list in Trello?

Tags: trello

I am trying out a new use case in Trello and playing with the idea of holding a list of Trello lists (Trello doesn't seem to support searching by lists).

Is this possible?

Comment: If you were able to create a link to a list, what would happen when you opened the link?  (i.e. how would it be different from a link to the board the list was on?)

Comment: @DanielLeCheminant Hmm I haven't thought about that. Seeing that there are only so many lists that can be displayed at once. Maybe it redirects to a view of the list on screen (an anchor?) Though that comes off as a feature request. So, let me give an example  https://trello.com/board/stack-overflow-polls-and-lists/4f226afbab9f83e1310a8260, say I have 100 lists of polls, they would just span the whole screen. What would be the easiest way to get to say the "What is the single most influential book every programmer should read?" list if it is not currently displayed on the screen?

Comment: There's already an implementation of displaying one list, sort of. If you make your window narrow (or view your board on iPhone), the display switches to a vertical format with tabs for each list. Clicking on a tab "scrolls" the window to put that list at the top of the screen. There's no direct link though. It would be weird to have this single-silo view show up in a typical wide browser window, but the example is a good jumping-off point for brainstorming Linking To A List.

Comment: Why is this question closed again?

Comment: @phwd This question is in the right spot and a valid question as that (I typed exactly this wording into google).  Your particular use-case may be different but the question should be open for others to opine, update etc

Comment: I don't know what's going on here at all - it's clearly an obviously useful thing completely different to linking to a board as the OP mentions in the comment - and I no idea why the question is closed

Comment: in case it's not obvious what people are talking about it's the idea of a "jump across" anchor like how a url can bring you to a section of a webpage - very elementary technology but very useful too

Comment: I do have the same need. First, in card descriptions, Trello displays links to cards or boards in a specific, convenient way. Being able to mention lists in the same way would be consistent, and useful : when writing a user’s guide for a board, for instance, you need to mention lists, and having them stand out and being clickable is a good thing. Second, as @byronyasgur pointed out, following the link could simply present the board scrolled to the left so that the list appears in first position.

Answer (score 3):

One of the ideas that's been brought up independently from several quarters is the ability to include a foreign list into your board, allowing you to create "mash-ups" of a bunch of different lists. It could initially be read-only, but later would allow you to copy or move cards from the included lists. Would this address your use case?

Comment: Maybe I'm not sure I feel as though this might be a bit leaning to something else. I'll try to gather my thoughts and shoot an email to feature-ideas@ if I don't find something that isn't in the development board. Thanks for trying to decipher